# Mod operator not working in C

Tags: c, modulo

Im trying to implement a cipher, and am supposed to work only in bits. However, the mod operator over 2 seems to give a value of 2. Can anyone tell me whats going wrong? The modulus operator is not working properly as far as I can tell.

Note: `fcsr1` and `fcsr2` are functions which just provide 80 bit long arrays as the input. The array values are all either 0 or 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int i=0,n=0;
        int ka[80],kb[80],rs[n];
        int *k1,*k2;


        printf("Enter the number of keystream bits : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        //Initialize all as 1
        for(i=0;i<80;i++){
            ka[i]=1;
            kb[i]=1;
        }
        int mb=0,ms=0;

        //Updating all 81 times
        k1=fcsr1(ka,&mb,81);
        k2=fcsr2(kb,&ms,81);

        for(i=0;i<n;i=i+2){
            k1=fcsr1(k1,&mb,1);
            k2=fcsr2(k2,&ms,1);

            int x0=k1[23];
            int x1=k1[73];
            int x2=k2[5];
            int x3=k2[9];
            int x4=k2[29];
            int x5=k1[51];

            //printf("%d %d %d %d %d %dNext",x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
            rs[i]=((x0*x1*x2*x4*x5+x0*x1*x2*x5+x0*x1*x2+x0*x1*x3*x5+x0*x1*x4*x5+x0*x1*x4+x0*x1*x5+x0*x1+x0*x2*x3*x4*x5+x0*x2*x3*x5+x0*x2*x3+x0*x2*x4*x5+x0*x2*x4+x0*x2+x0*x3*x4*x5+x0*x3*x4+x0*x3*x5+x0*x3+x0*x4*x5+x0*x4+x1*x2*x3*x5+x1*x2*x3+x1*x2*x4*x5+x1*x2*x4+x1*x2*x5+x1*x3*x4*x5+x1*x3*x4+x1*x3+x1*x4*x5+x1*x4+x1*x5+x2*x3*x5+x2*x3+x2*x5+x2+x3*x5+x4*x5+x5)%2);

            k2=fcsr2(k2,&ms,1);

            x0=k1[23];
            x1=k1[73];
            x2=k2[6];
            x3=k2[10];
            x4=k2[30];
            x5=k1[68];

            rs[i+1]=((x0*x1*x2*x4*x5+x0*x1*x2*x5+x0*x1*x2+x0*x1*x3*x5+x0*x1*x4*x5+x0*x1*x4+x0*x1*x5+x0*x1+x0*x2*x3*x4*x5+x0*x2*x3*x5+x0*x2*x3+x0*x2*x4*x5+x0*x2*x4+x0*x2+x0*x3*x4*x5+x0*x3*x4+x0*x3*x5+x0*x3+x0*x4*x5+x0*x4+x1*x2*x3*x5+x1*x2*x3+x1*x2*x4*x5+x1*x2*x4+x1*x2*x5+x1*x3*x4*x5+x1*x3*x4+x1*x3+x1*x4*x5+x1*x4+x1*x5+x2*x3*x5+x2*x3+x2*x5+x2+x3*x5+x4*x5+x5)%2);
            //printf("%d %d %d %d %d %dEnd",x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);
            printf("%d %d ",rs[i],rs[i+1]);
        }   
    }
```

result:

```
Enter the number of keystream bits :
24
0 0 1 0 0 1 2 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 24
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: did you intentionally set the dimensions of rs to 0? (`n=0, int rs[n]`) array out-of-bounds accesses is a classic c failure...

Answer (score 6):

> `int i=0,n=0;
>
> int ka[80],kb[80],rs[n];`

The size of `rs` does not magically change when the value of `n` changes.

Presumably `rs[i]` is being overwritten by some assignment to x<sub>j</sub> for some value of i and j.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of `rs` until *after* you've read the value for `n`:

```
    int ka[80],kb[80]
    int *k1,*k2;


    printf("Enter the number of keystream bits : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // validate that n is > 0

    int rs[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you're allocating rs with zero elements, so the answer is junk.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of rs array. You have n=0 and then declaring rs[n].